# Pandas: Search input data against values in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have 2 data sources - config and input data

**Config**

```
+------------+-------+
| ContractID | PB ID |
+------------+-------+
| H9500      | 002   |
+------------+-------+
| H9500      | 008   |
+------------+-------+
| H3544      | 800   |
+------------+-------+
| H3544      | 801   |
+------------+-------+
| H3544      | 802   |
+------------+-------+
```

**Input file**

```
+-------+------------+-------+
| Index | ContractID | PB ID |
+-------+------------+-------+
| 1     | H9500      | 456   |
+-------+------------+-------+
| 2     | H9500      | 008   |
+-------+------------+-------+
| 3     | H9500      | 002   |
+-------+------------+-------+
| 4     | H3544      | 853   |
+-------+------------+-------+
| 5     | H3544      | 802   |
+-------+------------+-------+
| 6     | H4599      | 465   |
+-------+------------+-------+
```

I'm trying to loop through the input file and check if the Contract ID is valid or not. If a `Contract ID = H9500` and `PB ID= 456` is Invalid because that combination is not present in the config file. `Contract ID = H9500` and `PB ID= 008` is valid because that combination is present in config file.

I'm using the below logic

```
input_df=pd.DataFrame({'Index': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                      'ContractID' : ['H9500','H9500','H9500','H3544','H3544','H4599'],
                       'PBID': ['456','008','002','853','802','465']})

config_df=pd.DataFrame({'ContractID':['H9500','H9500','H3544','H3544','H3544'],
                        'PBID':['002','008','800','801','802']})

config_dict={k: list(v) for k,v in config_df.groupby("ContractID")["PBID"]}

def test_6_3(s):
    if config_dict.get(s["ContractID"]) and s["PBID"] not in config_dict.values():
        return "Invalid PB Contract"
    else:
        return "Valid"
    
input_df['test_6_3'] = input_df.apply(test_6_3, axis=1)

input_df
```

But I'm not getting the **expected result**

```
+-------+------------+-------+----------+
| Index | ContractID | PB ID | test_6_3 |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+
| 1     | H9500      | 456   | Invalid  |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+
| 2     | H9500      | 008   | Valid    |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+
| 3     | H9500      | 002   | Valid    |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+
| 4     | H3544      | 853   | Invalid  |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+
| 5     | H3544      | 802   | Valid    |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+
| 6     | H4599      | 465   | Invalid  |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** (based on corrected input by OP):

This should do what your question asks:

```py
df = input_df.join(config_df.assign(test_6_3='Valid').set_index(['ContractID', 'PBID']), on = ['ContractID', 'PBID']).fillna('Invalid')
```

Input:

```
   Index ContractID PBID
0      1      H9500  456
1      2      H9500  008
2      3      H9500  002
3      4      H3544  853
4      5      H3544  802
5      6      H4599  465
  ContractID PBID
0      H9500  002
1      H9500  008
2      H3544  800
3      H3544  801
4      H3544  802
```

Output:

```
   Index ContractID PBID test_6_3
0      1      H9500  456  Invalid
1      2      H9500  008    Valid
2      3      H9500  002    Valid
3      4      H3544  853  Invalid
4      5      H3544  802    Valid
5      6      H4599  465  Invalid
```

**UPDATE #2:**

To stick with the `apply()` approach in OP's question and make it work, you can modify `test_6_3()` as follows:

```py
def test_6_3(s):
    if s["ContractID"] in config_dict and s["PBID"] in config_dict[s["ContractID"]]:
        return "Valid"
    else:
        return "Invalid"
```

Output:

```
   Index ContractID PBID test_6_3
0      1      H9500  456  Invalid
1      2      H9500  008    Valid
2      3      H9500  002    Valid
3      4      H3544  853  Invalid
4      5      H3544  802    Valid
5      6      H4599  465  Invalid
```

Comment: Thank you! I just updated the Input dataframe with 'H9500'

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer to match.

Comment: This is definitely a great solution using join. I'm using apply method in all other tests that I have (around 30). Is it possible to use the template function? what is wrong with the function?

Comment: See my updated answer for an example of how to fix the function you pass as an argument to `apply()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['ContractID', 'PBID']
config = dfc[names].apply(tuple, axis=1).to_list()
config
```

Output:

```
[('H9500', 2), ('H9500', 8), ('H3544', 800), ('H3544', 801), ('H3544', 802)]
```

code:

```
(
    df.assign(test_6_3=df[names].apply(lambda x: tuple(x) in config, axis=1))
    .assign(test_6_3=lambda x: x.test_6_3.map({True: 'Valid', False: 'Invalid'}))
)
```

Output:

```
   Index ContractID  PBID test_6_3
0      1      H9500   456  Invalid
1      2      H9500     8    Valid
2      3      H9500     2    Valid
3      4      H3544   853  Invalid
4      5      H3544   802    Valid
5      6      H4599   465  Invalid
```